# Stack Implementation using array

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I made this program on stack implementation using array. It is running in an infinite loop without asking the user for input.

Can someone point out the necessary changes required in this program. The code is running and has no compile error, there is a logical error of where to place the CreateStack().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Stack has three properties. capacity stands for the maximum number of  elements stack can hold.
    top stands for the current size of the stack and array is the array of elements */

typedef struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
}stack;


stack* CreateStack(int);
void StackDestroy(stack*);

int StackIsEmpty(stack*);
int StackIsFull(stack*);

void StackPush(stack*, int);
int StackPop(stack*);

void Display(stack*);
void StackSearch(stack*, int);

int StackTop(stack*);
int StackSize(stack*);


/* CreateStack function takes as argument the maximum number of elements the stack can hold, creates
  a stack according to it and returns a pointer to the stack. */

stack* CreateStack(int maxSize)
{
    /* Create a stack*/
    stack *s;
    s=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));

    /* Initialize it's properties*/
    s->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxSize);

    s->capacity=maxSize;
    s->top=-1;

    return s;
}


/* StackDestroy function will destroy the stack after the function is   called. */

void StackDestroy(stack *s)
{
    free(s->array);

    s->array=NULL;
    s->capacity=0;
    s->top=-1;
}


int StackIsEmpty(stack *s)
{
    return s->top<0;
}


int StackIsFull(stack *s)
{
    return (s->top==s->capacity-1);
}


void StackPush(stack *s,int data)
{
    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s->array[++s->top]=data;
}


int StackPop(stack *s)
{
    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return (s->array[s->top--]);
}


void Display(stack *s)
{
    int i;

    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
        printf("Stack Is Empty\n");

    else
        for(i=s->top;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%d\n", s->array[i]);
}


void StackSearch(stack *s, int data)
{
    int i, j, element;
    int counter = 0;
    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
        printf("Stack Is Empty\n");

    else
    {
        for(i=s->top,j=1;i>=0;i--,j++)
        {
            if(data==s->array[i])
            {
                counter++;
                printf("Element %d found at position %d",element, j);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        if(counter == 0)
            printf("Element not found in stack\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int StackTop(stack *s)
{
    return s->array[s->top];
}


int StackSize(stack *s)
{
    return s->top;
}

int main() {
    int choice, item, size;

    printf("Enter size of stack:");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    stack *s = CreateStack(size);

    printf("Implementation of Stack\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\nMain Menu");
        printf("\n1.Push \n2.Pop \n3.Search \n4.Display \n5.Stack Top \n6.Stack Size \n7.Destroy Stack \n8.exit");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter The element to be pushed");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                StackPush(s, item);
            break;

            case 2:
                item =StackPop(s);
                printf("\nThe popped element is %d", item);
            break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nEnter element to be searched");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                StackSearch(s, item);
            break;

            case 4:
                Display(s);
            break;

            case 5:
                item=StackTop(s);
                printf("\nThe last inserted element is %d",item);
            break;

            case 6:
                item=StackSize(s);
                printf("\nThe size of stack is %d",item);
            break;

            case 7:
                StackDestroy(s);
            break;

            case 8:
                exit(0);
        }
    } while(1);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix indentation. Please.

Comment: And `CreateStack` is only creating, not returning..

Comment: You don't have compiler errors, but I bet you have warnings (if not turned off..)

Comment: When I run that code, it asks me for input, and does not go into an infinite loop. Either you posted the wrong code, or you're not telling us "the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it" in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @DanGetz there is a UB, so you might not get the same result as OP does.

Comment: @Priya Sharma Please don't fix the code in the question on the fly. It is invalidating the valid answers.

Comment: I am using ideone.com (online compiler), it is not asking for any input.

Comment: You appear to misunderstand how websites work :/

Comment: It doesn't look like ideone.com will emulate an interactive terminal with input and output for you. You should be compiling and running programs like this on your own computer.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by having `CreateStack` return something, as it is expected to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I tried [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and it is not asking for user input. So I suggest you to install a compiler to your own computer and compile yourself.

**1.** Your if statement in `StackPush(stack, int)` method is wrong, it should be `StackIsFull(stack)`, not `StackIsEmpty(stack)`

```
void StackPush(stack *s, int data)
{
    if(StackIsFull(s))
    {
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s->array[++s->top] = data;
}
```

**2.** You didn't used the variable `element` in your `StackSearch(stack, int)` method. So I replaced it with the variable `data`

```
void StackSearch(stack *s, int data)
{
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;

    if(StackIsEmpty(s)){
        printf("Stack Is Empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = s->top, j = 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--, j++)
        {
            if(data == s->array[i])
            {
                counter++;
                printf("Element %d found at position %d\n", data, j);
            }
        }

        if(counter == 0)
            printf("Element not found in stack\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Also, for the record, this method prints the index based from top, not bottom.

Those are the only important changes I've made. But I've made some changes to fix code format and output format, you can find the complete code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Stack has three properties. capacity stands for the maximum number of  elements stack can hold.
    top stands for the current size of the stack and array is the array of elements */
typedef struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
}stack;


stack* CreateStack(int);
void StackDestroy(stack*);

int StackIsEmpty(stack*);
int StackIsFull(stack*);

void StackPush(stack*, int);
int StackPop(stack*);

void Display(stack*);
void StackSearch(stack*, int);

int StackTop(stack*);
int StackSize(stack*);


/* CreateStack function takes as argument the maximum number of elements the stack can hold, creates
  a stack according to it and returns a pointer to the stack. */
stack* CreateStack(int maxSize)
{
    /* Create a stack*/
    stack *s;
    s = (stack*) malloc(sizeof(stack));

    /* Initialize it's properties*/
    s->array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * maxSize);

    s->capacity = maxSize;
    s->top = -1;

    return s;
}


/* StackDestroy function will destroy the stack after the function is   called. */
void StackDestroy(stack *s)
{
    free(s->array);

    s->array = NULL;
    s->capacity = 0;
    s->top = -1;

    printf("Stack is destroyed.\n");
}


int StackIsEmpty(stack *s)
{
    return s->top < 0;
}


int StackIsFull(stack *s)
{
    return (s->top == s->capacity-1);
}


void StackPush(stack *s, int data)
{
    if(StackIsFull(s))
    {
        printf("Cannot push, stack overflow.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        s->array[++s->top] = data;
    }
}


int StackPop(stack *s)
{
    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("Cannot pop, stack is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        return (s->array[s->top--]);
    }
}


void Display(stack *s)
{
    int i;

    if(StackIsEmpty(s))
        printf("Stack Is Empty\n");

    else{

        printf("___STACK___\n");

        for(i = s->top ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            printf("%3d: %d\n", i, s->array[i]);
        }
    }
}


void StackSearch(stack *s, int data)
{
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;

    if(StackIsEmpty(s)){
        printf("Stack Is Empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = s->top, j = 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--, j++)
        {
            if(data == s->array[i])
            {
                counter++;
                printf("Element %d found at position %d\n", data, j);
            }
        }

        if(counter == 0)
            printf("Element not found in stack\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int StackTop(stack *s)
{
    return s->array[s->top];
}


int StackSize(stack *s)
{
    return s->top;
}

int main() {
    int choice, item, size;

    printf("Enter size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    stack *s = CreateStack(size);

    printf("Implementation of Stack\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\nMain Menu");
        printf("\n1.Push \n2.Pop \n3.Search \n4.Display \n5.Stack Top \n6.Stack Size \n7.Destroy Stack \n8.exit");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter The element to be pushed: ");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                StackPush(s, item);
            break;

            case 2:
                item = StackPop(s);
                printf("\nThe popped element is %d", item);
            break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nEnter element to be searched: ");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                StackSearch(s, item);
            break;

            case 4:
                Display(s);
            break;

            case 5:
                item=StackTop(s);
                printf("\nThe last inserted element is %d",item);
            break;

            case 6:
                item = StackSize(s);
                printf("\nThe size of stack is %d", item + 1);
            break;

            case 7:
                StackDestroy(s);
            break;

            case 8:
                exit(0);
        }
    } while(1);


    return 0;
}
```